# No Qualifying Bean of Type […] IsAvailable

Tags: java, spring

I have the following structure:

**WebService**

```
@Autowired
public FooService(@Qualifier("fooMapper1") FooBO fooBO1,
        @Qualifier("fooMapper2") FooBO fooBO2,
        @Qualifier("fooMapper3") FooBO fooBO3) {
    this.fooBO1= fooBO1;
    this.fooBO2= fooBO2;
    this.fooBO3= fooBO3;
}
```

**Configuration**

```
@Configuration
public class MapperConfig {

    @Bean("fooMapper1")
    public FooBO oneMapper(FooOneMapper mapper) {
        return new FooBO(mapper);
    }
    @Bean("fooMapper2")
    public FooBO twoMapper(FooTwoMapper mapper) {
        return new FooBO(mapper);
    }
    @Bean("fooMapper3")
    public FooBO threeMapper(FooThreeMapper mapper) {
        return new FooBO(mapper);
    }
}
```

**FooBO**

```
    @Autowired
    public FooBO(IFooMapper mapper) {
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }
```

**IFooMapper** is and interface that is extended by **FooOneMapper**, **FooTwoMapper** and **FooThreeMapper**.

When I try to run the project the following message is throwing:

```
Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in ...FooBO required a single bean, but 4 were found:
    - FooOneMapper: defined in file [C:...\mapper\FooOneMapper.class]
    - FooTwoMapper: defined in file [C:...\mapper\FooTwoMapper.class]
    - FooThreeMapper: defined in file [C:...\mapper\FooThreeMapper.class]
    - IFooMapper: defined in file [C:...\mapper\IFooMapper.class]


Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

I don't understand why spring have this conflict with the beans being that all seems to be well configured.

Comment: I don't think you want `@Autowired` on your `FooBO` constructor, as you construct them manually.

Comment: I agree and remove the `@Autowired` but still throwing the same error

Comment: Do you have the @Component annotation or something that includes it over your FooBO class?

Comment: Yes, FooBoo have **@Component** annotation also the mappers implementations have **@Mapper**

Comment: @Andres as `FooBO` is marked as `@Component` spring will try to create a bean using by scanning the components. Check below-posted answer with more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you have annotated `FooBO` with `@Component` annotation.

> the root package containing Spring Boot main class s is scanned to look for any @Component-annotated classes, and those classes are registered as Spring bean definitions within the container

You are creating beans in the configuration class. Make sure `FooBO` and `IFooMapper` are not annotated with `@Component` or its stereotype annotation.

```
class FooBO {

    private final IFooMapper mapper;

    public FooBO(IFooMapper mapper) {
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }
}
```

If for some reason you cannot remove `@Component`. Other ways to fix would be to mark one of the implementation of `IFooMapper` as primary using `@Primary`

```
@Component
@Primary
class FooOneMapper implements IFooMapper{

}
```

or provide additional data to help spring resolve dependency.

```
public FooBO(@Qualifier("fooThreeMapper") IFooMapper mapper) {
    this.mapper = mapper;
}
```

Comment: I don't know exactly why but when I remove **@Component** from FooBO as you sugest the project start fine, thanks!

Comment: It was not working because of Spring component scanning mechanism. Spring automatically creates a bean for every @Component marked class. in your case `FooBO`, but `FooBO's` dependency IFooMapper has 3 implementations. How can spring understand which one to use?

Answer (score 0):

First Spring does a scan to find the beans it has in the application context. It finds your `@Configuration` that creates three beans of type `FooBO` (and implicitly also of type `IFooMapper`). It also finds other beans you defined with annotatoins or in your xml - so it finds `IFooMapper`.
Secondly, Spring finds your `@Autowired` FooBO constructor and it has to decide what bean you want to inject there. It's default strategy is to inject based on the type of the bean. So it looks what beans of type `IFooMapper` are there in the current context. It finds the three in your configuration and anything else you declared in other places. It throws an exception because it cannot decide what instance to use. If you annotate one of the beans `@Primay` then Spring will always use that one in such situations.

Extra reading:
[Spring bean lifecycle](https://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-bean-life-cycle-tutorial) / [Spring autowiring](https://dzone.com/articles/autowiring-in-spring)